# CRSP: Return including dividends

Tags: asset-pricing, dividends, return, crsp

Using CRSP data, I tried to compute the historical returns (including dividends) of stocks according to

*Total Return = (adjprc + (divamt / cumfacpr / facpr)) / prev_adjprc – 1*,

where *divamt* is the dividend amount in period, *cumfacpr* is the cumulative factor to adjust prices over a date range, *facpr* is the factor to adjust price in period, *adjprc* is the price adjusted at the end of period, *prev_adjprc* is the price adjusted at the end of previous period (see https://www.crsp.org/products/documentation/crsp-calculations). But I see often such cases:

[image]

Does somebody known why RET = RETX = *adjprc / prev_adjprc – 1*? I thought RET correspond to returns including dividends and should be equal to *Total Return* as defined above?

Furthermore, I found:

[image]

Here RET = *(adjprc + (divamt / cumfacpr)) / prev_adjprc – 1* > RETX, which implies that *facpr* should be equal to 1, although the above table states *facpr=0* (which means *Total Return* cannot be computed as shown above as we would divide by zero).

Could someone explain that to me, please? :)

Comment: I suspect the first case is a non-cash dividend (eg. a distribution of shares in some spinoff). I believe DIVAMT will show the USD value of non-cash distributions, but it isn't excluded from RETX because, ["while ordinary and certain other regular taxable dividends are excluded from the returns calculation, non-ordinary distributions are included."](https://www.crsp.org/products/documentation/data-definitions-r)